# IdentityServer3 - CustomViewService Vs DefaultViewService

Tags: css, identityserver3

I would like to change the look and feel of the login page that is served up by IdentityServer3.

Effectively i would like to add a selection of stylesheets (as its used across multiple sites) that can be added. I am also looking to include an additional "Register" button that will take you too another page along with a forgot password link.

I know i can add the forgot password link in the LoginPageLinks list on startup, but the modification for registration i dont think will work this way. (Please correct if im wrong)

I have read the ID3 documentation on modification and it appears i can get most of what i want by modifying the DefaultViewService, however a custom View service (implementing the IViewService) seems to give me everything, but you have to have all of the assets in place explicitly in my solution (js/css/html/less/fonts).
What i want to know is am i missing something here? is the DefaultViewService the answer? and how modifiable is it really? as i dont really want to go down the root of the implementing a custom view.

Comment: Yes, just use the default view service and add/modify the ~/templates files.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 100% custom IViewService is rarely the way to go, as it's a lot of work. You can always implement custom HTML templates to add your CSS and whatever custom markup you want. If you need it to be dynamic, then you can look into deriving from the `DefaultViewService` and overriding the appropriate methods to add what you need at runtime.